# Autowire not working with org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisProperties

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to autowire the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisProperties in a library that is used in a SpringBoot application and I've got an error that the bean type cannot be found. During build time I have no issues.

The library were I would like to retrieve some values from the ArtemisProperties class. 
The pom.xml from this library imports the artemis libraries.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.ems.microservice.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>CoreLibrary</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>  


  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
          <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>
            <artifactId>apm-agent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-manifests</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Within the library I've got a class where I would like to have some values of the host where Artemis is trying to connect

```
package com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue;

import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisProperties;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageDispatcherConfiguration.DispatchInfo;

import co.elastic.apm.api.CaptureSpan;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

// Message Dispatcher
@Component
@EnableJms
@Slf4j
public class MessageDispatcher {
    @Autowired
    MessageDispatcherConfiguration messageDispatcherConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    MessageSender messageSender;

   @Autowired
   private ArtemisProperties artemisProperties;



    private void sendFile(DispatchInfo dispatcheInfo, MessageInformationExtractor messageInformationExtractorForDispatch, EMSFileMessage emsFileMessage, int ... priority) throws EMSQueueException{
        if (hasToBeSend(dispatcheInfo, messageInformationExtractorForDispatch, emsFileMessage)){
            for (String destinationQueue:dispatcheInfo.getDestinationQueueNames()){ 
                log.debug("Will send {} to {}:{}  and queue {}", emsFileMessage.getId(), artemisProperties.getHost(), artemisProperties.getPort(), destinationQueue);
                messageSender.send(destinationQueue, emsFileMessage, priority); 
            } ;
        }
    }
....
```

In my spring-boot application pom.xml I'm including the dependency with the library and I am including the component scan for the classes within the library:

```
package com.xxx.ems.microservice.msdiskloader;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

import com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.app.EMSMicroserviceApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.ems")
@Configuration  
@EnableAsync 
public class MSDiskLoaderApplication extends EMSMicroserviceApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EMSMicroserviceApplication.run(MSDiskLoaderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Any clue why I have this autowired error? The dependency from the artemis libraries have been properly added. Might the any incompatibility with other libraries?

The full error is the following

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field artemisProperties in com.xxx.ems.microservice.core.queue.MessageDispatcher required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisProperties' in your configuration.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` and  auto-configurations are not public APIs so I would strongly suggest you not to use that in your own code. This bean is created by the auto-configuration, if your custom code makes it backs-off, it won't be created anymore.

`@EnableConfigurationProperties(ArtemisProperties.class)` is the best way to make sure it is registered in the context and bound to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
First create a bean of ArtemisProperties and set properties in it and then you can autowired it. 
@Bean 
public ArtemisProperties artemisProperties () { 
ArtemisProperties artemisObj = new ArtemisProperties(); 
return artemisObj; 
} 

@Autowired private ArtemisProperties artemis;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```